# Flash drive detected by lsusb but not by fdisk

Tags: devices, usb-drive, fdisk

I try to format `SanDisk Ultra microSDHC UHS-I Card with adapter` but it does not appear on `fdisk -l`.
However, it does appear on `lsusb` as `Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1908:0222 GEMBIRD`

Comment: It has a note "for better photos and full HD video" maybe it is for photos and video only?

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1586206

Comment: Check whether `usb_storage` kernel module is loaded (via `lsmod` command).
If not, then try `modprobe usb_storage` and then reattach drive.

Also output from `dmesg` can be helpful so we can better understand what happened.

Comment: Commonly those adapters are based on  realtek chipsets and need their own driver. If you are really unlucky, it might only work in windows.